# Data validation, only 2 options (so or)

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I have the following code:

```
If StrSoort = "Tussen_Een_en_Vijf" Then   bKolomHidden = "False"   Range(StrBereik).Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateDecimal, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween, Formula1:="1", Formula2:="5"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "Only values between 1 and 5"
        .ErrorMessage = "Only values between 1 and 5"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

It checks whether the input values is between 1 and 5. 
Instead I would like to change this to validate either 1 or 5. However I can't find an `or`/ `XlOr`.
How can I make this work?

Comment: Is it "1"," 5" in formula1?

Comment: No, it's not "1, 5". Thats the same as forumla1:="1", Formula2:="5"

Answer (score 0):

I believe they will have to be added individually as the cell address is required.

```
dim dv as range
for each dv in Selection
  with dv.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=or(" & dv.address(0, 0) & "=1," & dv.address(0, 0) & "=5)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = "only 1 or 5"
    .ErrorMessage = "only 1 or 5"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
  End With
next dv
```

Comment: With the cell address requirement you mean that for every cell I want to validate I have to input this as a range in the code?

Comment: Well, I looped through every cell in Selection but I also left the address relative so why not try to copy it somewhere else?